# Select Max and Select other column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

I am trying to get the max + 1 value from one column, and all of the values from another column. However, my query does not give any results.

For example,

```
 SectionItemID   SectionItem
 1                    blue
 2                    red
```

The query should return

```
SectionItemID    SectionItem
3                    blue
                     red
```

Heres what I have

```
SELECT SectionItem,MAX(SectionItemID) + 1 AS SectionItemID FROM Core.SectionItem_Lkup
```

Comment: `my query is not correct.` I believe you should define what exactly is wrong with your query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SectionItem,
       (select MAX(SectionItemID)+1 FROM Core.SectionItem_Lkup) AS SectionItemID
FROM Core.SectionItem_Lkup
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you `GROUP BY`, you *should* aggregate the other columns involved.

- Mysql does allow to omit aggregation on other colums
- MsSQL does not, cause the result is undefined for columns without Aggregation.

Best way *is* to aggregate other columns. For your szenario, you could use `group_concat`

```
  SELECT MAX(SectionItemID)+1, Group_concat(SectionItem) FROM tbl
```

Note: The query does not contain any `Group By`, because you dont want to group on `SectionItemId` nor `SectionItem`. Omiting the `Group By` and using aggregate-functions will use them on the whole table.

Output:

```
MAX(SECTIONITEMID)+1    GROUP_CONCAT(SECTIONITEM)
3                     blue,red
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/353bf3/6

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when t2.SectionItem = 'blue' 
    then cast(max(t1.SectionItemID) + 1 as varchar(1))
    else '' end 
as SectionItemID
, t2.SectionItem
from Core.SectionItem_Lkup t1
full outer join Core.SectionItem_Lkup t2 on 1 = 1
group by t2.SectionItem
order by 
case when t2.SectionItem = 'blue' 
    then cast(max(t1.SectionItemID) + 1 as varchar(1))
    else '' end 
desc
```

Comment: This will return exactly the output you've shown here.